# AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING IV - Encryption in NodeJs (Encrypted in Python)

Tags: python, node.js, aes

I am trying to encrypt in NodeJs. It is working in Python. But I am not able to achieve same in Node.

Please find my NodeJs code:

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');
const config = {
  host: 'http://******',
  appkey: 'app',
  secret: "****", // length is 32
  iv: "****" // length is 16
}

function enCryptoAes (data, key, iv = '') {
    let clearEncoding = 'utf8';
    let cipherEncoding = 'base64';
    let cipherChunks = [];
    let algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc'
    switch(key.length) {
        case 16:
            algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc'
            break;
        case 32:
            algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'
            break;
    }
    let cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    cipherChunks.push(cipher.update(data, clearEncoding, cipherEncoding));
    cipherChunks.push(cipher.final(cipherEncoding));

    return cipherChunks.join('');
}

function getParamsAesStr(params) {
  let paramsArr = Object.keys(params).map(key => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
  paramsArr = paramsArr.sort()

  let signStr = Buffer.from(paramsArr.join('').toLowerCase(), 'utf-8').toString()
  let sign = Crypto.createHmac('md5', config.secret).update(signStr).digest('hex')
 
  let paramsStr = `${paramsArr.join('&')}&sign=${sign}`
  
  let paramsAesStr = enCryptoAes(paramsStr, config.secret.slice(0, 16), config.iv)
  paramsAesStr = Buffer.from(paramsStr, 'utf-8').toString('base64')
  return paramsAesStr
}
```

Please find working Python decryption code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import requests
import base64
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import hashlib
import hmac


BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad_fn = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad_fn = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]


appkey = "app"
secret = bytes.fromhex("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
secret_Str  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

issueTypeId_Bug = 10201
issueTypeId_Task = 10002


def hmac_md5(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.md5).hexdigest()

def process_aes_key(key):
    if key is None:
        return None
    length = 16
    if len(key) == length:
        return key

    if len(key) > 16:
        return key[0:16]
    else:
        padding_count = 16 - len(key)
        xs = bytearray(key)
        for i in range(padding_count):
            xs.append(0)

        return bytes(xs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bug_info = {
        "pageNo":1,
        "pageSize":10
    }

    param_list = []
    for key in bug_info:
        param_list.append("{0}={1}".format(key, bug_info.get(key)))

    param_list.sort()
    all_str = "".join(param_list)
    all_str = all_str.lower()

    params_bytes = bytes(all_str, encoding="UTF-8")
    secret_bytes = bytes(secret_Str, encoding="UTF-8")
    #
    # 32 bits. secret
    sign = hmac_md5(secret_bytes, all_str.encode('utf-8'))
    bug_info['sign'] = sign

    # 16 bits. secret
    cryptor = AES.new(process_aes_key(secret), AES.MODE_CBC, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".encode("utf-8"))
    request_praram = urlencode(bug_info)
    encrypt_text = cryptor.encrypt(pad_fn(request_praram))

    base_encode_bytes = base64.b64encode(encrypt_text)
    final_param_str = base_encode_bytes.decode('utf-8')

    # final_p = {
    #    "appkey": "xxx",
    #    "param": final_param_str
    # }

    # s = session.post(create_bug_url, headers=request_headers, data=final_p, allow_redirects=True)

    # print(s.status_code, s.text)
```

The expected encrypted text is：
"6lzGZRetu2vccBJOftXKl0MXPNjOLYuu/4OK8NFNCkFIkZ1LnaZq2CApYQGk2V5tiAEk3EHY5S+QiWE/Qc6CHA=="

ps: I'm not sure it can be reproduced by the Python code whitch is a demo provied by the Python code auther.

The encrypted text of Node is：
"cGFnZU5vPTEmcGFnZVNpemU9MTAmc2lnbj1kMzBhZGI0MGUxM2RlYTQzYzEzMDhkOTAzZTJkOWFjMw=="

```
getParamsAesStr({pageNo: 1, pageSize: 10})
```

I am getting a different encrypted text. I am not able to achieve the same result in NodeJs as they did in Python.
I'm not familiar with Python。What's wrong with my NodeJs code?

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: This is quite far from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would recommend you to divide the code functionally, test these units separately to isolate where the results differ.

Comment: Thanks，I had deleted some unnecessary Nodejs code。 But I'm not familiar with Python。

Comment: The Python code (is it Python2?) seems to encrypt and not decrypt: `cryptor.encrypt(...)` (which is not a problem, since identical test input data must result in the same ciphertext). Thus, please post for the Python code a concrete example with test data: plaintext, key, IV and ciphertext. Likewise, in the NodeJS code, please post that part where you call the methods in conjunction with this test data.

Comment: Ok，I have  post  the test data and called function and result text

Comment: Yes，is encrypt，not decrypt。

Comment: The NodeJS code does not give the posted result. The Python code is inconsistent with the NodeJS code regarding the test data and even after adjustment the posted result cannot be reproduced. I vote to close this post.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you for my mistake。Inorder to divide the code functionally, I edited some of the code which I mistook it for nothing。And posted the result of the original Node code。But now the posted result is reproduced by the posted code。And the encrypted text of python code was expected result，I'm not sure it can be reproduced by the Python code whitch is a demo provied by the Python code auther.

Comment: You didn't bother me. It's just that the information is not sufficient to answer the question or leaves a lot of room for misinterpretation. The Python code still does not produce the posted result. If the Python code is to be used as reference code, then the result must be reproducible. So, please use _consistent_ test data with both the Python code and the NodeJS code and generate the corresponding ciphertexts.

Comment: Thanks， I have solve the problem。